# String concatenation using snprintf

Tags: c, string

I am making a string using `snprintf()`:

```
snprintf(msgText, MAX_MSG_SIZE-1, "expr $((($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r filename.txt)) / 86400))");
```

This is intended to store a Linux command in `msgText`.  The command will get executed later and output the age of `filename.txt` in days.

Issue here is:

This is wrong, as `snprintf` expects `%s` to have a string argument. The compiler reports this error:

```
error: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument
```

What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps read the manual page and escape the %

Comment: Or just use `strncpy()` since `sprintf()` is for formatting a string, which you're not doing here.

Comment: Be careful with `strncpy()`; it does not guarantee null termination.  But I agree that using `snprintf()` to do a simple string copy is a little bit of overkill.

Comment: Why are you invoking a shell to do this, anyway?  Just `stat()` the file and compute the value in C - much more efficient, more reliable, more maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `%s` to be substituted, then provide `const char*` arguments to `snprintf` with the value to write.

If you want literal `%s` in `msgText`, then either escape the `%` as `%%`, or pass the string as a single argument to a format string of `"%s"`:

```
snprintf(msgText, MAX_MSG_SIZE-1, "%s", "$(date +%s) ...");
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be invoking a shell and two `date` processes for something as simple as this.  You should just `stat()` the file and subtract its mtime from the current time in C:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

double age(const char *path) {
    struct stat buf;

    if (stat(path, &buf)) {
        perror("stat");
        return -1;
    }

    time_t now = time(NULL);
    if (time < 0) {
        perror("time");
        return -1;
    }

    return difftime(now, buf.st_mtime) / 86400;
}
```

The test program can be very simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv)
        printf("%s: %.0f days\n", *argv, age(*argv));
}
```